# Problems using the same function of a custom hook while testing with enzyme using hookRender() and act()

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-hooks, enzyme, react-testing-library

**So i have this custom hook:** (it just increase, decrease and reset)

```
import { useState } from 'react';
export const useCounter = (initialState = 1) => {

    const [counter, setCounter] = useState(initialState);
    const increase = (factor = 1) =>{
        setCounter(counter + factor);
    }
    const decrease = (factor = 1) =>{
        setCounter(counter - factor);
    }
    const reset = () =>{
        setCounter(initialState)
    }
    return {
        counter,
        increment,
        decrease,
        reset
    };
};
```

I would like to test it by calling decrease two time, but it does not do the same effect twice, if I just put decrease() once and value expected to be 99,it works and the test pass. But i was wondering if it is possible to call decrease() twice. I leave the test below.

```
import "@testing-library/jest-dom";
import { renderHook, act } from "@testing-library/react-hooks";
import { useCounter } from "../../hooks/useCounter";

describe("Test useCounter", () => {
    test("should decrease two times", () => {
        const { result, rerender } = renderHook(() => useCounter(100));
        const { decrease } = result.current;
        act(() => {
            decrease();
            decrease();
        });

        const { counter } = result.current;
        expect(counter).toBe(98);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you are treating state like it is synchronous, but it is not.

State does not update until a re-render happens.

When you call `decrease()` twice, you are essentially saying:

```
setCounter(100 - 1)
setCounter(100 - 1)
```

No matter how many times you call it, the counter will only decrement by 1.

This is because the `counter` state value doesn't change during the same render.

To use the most up to date value when setting state, you need to change your set state to use a callback function:

```
setCounter(prev => prev - factor)
```

This will work as expected.

In general, you should *always* use a callback function when the new state value depends on the old state value. In your case, the new value uses the old value, so you should be using a callback function.

You should also change your `increase` function in the same way.